# Leaving "zombie" flag upon object destruction

Tags: c++

I want to explicitly destroy an object (call the destructor on it and all its fields), but it may happen that I still hold some pointers to the object in question. Thus, I don't want to yet free the memory; instead I would like to leave a sort of a flag "I am a destroyed object".

I came with an idea of the following approach:

```
class BaseClass { //all objects in question derive from this class
public:
    BaseClass() : destroyed(false) {}
    virtual ~BaseClass() {}
private:
    bool destroyed;
public:
    bool isDestroyed() { return destroyed; }
    void destroy() {
        this->~BaseClass(); //this will call the virtual destructor of a derivative class
        new(this) BaseClass();
        destroyed=true;
    }
};
```

When `destroy` is called, I basically destroy the whatever object I had (perhaps a derivative one) and create a new "zombie" one in that very same place. As a result I hope to achieve:

- Any other pointer `ptr` previously pointing to this object can still call `ptr->isDestroyed()` to verify its existence.
- I am aware that if I don't check the flag of the zombie and try to access fields belonging to any derived object, bad things may happen
- I am aware that the zombie object still consumes as much memory as the destroyed object (as it may be a derivative of `BaseClass`)
- I still have to free memory of the destroyed object. I hope however, that calling `delete` is still correct?

**Questions:**

Are there any other problems which I should consider when using the above pattern?

Will calling `delete` on the zombie object correctly free whole memory consumed by the previous (normal) object?

---

While I appreciate your input on how to do it differently, and I may be inclined to do it your way - I would still like to understand all the risks that the above code poses.

Comment: It seems you are looking for [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

Comment: if you use smart pointers religiously, this should not be a problem.

Comment: This is a bad idea. Use smart pointers.

Comment: `new(this) BaseClass();` - I'm pretty sure all bets are off after this if `this` was "originally of a derived type".

Comment: I am using reference-counted smart pointers to manage my memory, but they alone are not powerful enough. (check my edit I just added)

Comment: @CygnusX1 - This is some of the stupidest and idiotic code I have seen for a long time. What the hell are you trying to achieve?!

Comment: @CygnusX1 Take a look at [weak_ptr::expired](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982208.aspx).

Comment: _"If an object is flagged as "weak", all its member pointers release their references and should not be used."_ By "member pointers" do you mean: "all pointers that point to the weakened object"?

Comment: @Branko: No, I mean all pointers that the weakened object holds as its members.

Comment: @CygnusX1, surprise - that's exactly how `weak_ptr` works.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/6176334#6176334

Comment: @Griwes: Sorry, I don't get what you are saying?

Comment: @CygnusX1, which part of what I am saying you don't get, exactly?

Comment: @Griwes: `weak_ptr` is not exactly the same as a "weak" object. You also post a link, which I follow, but I don't know what I should be looking at over there. I see some discussion about tuples over there.

Comment: If your solution works for you, perfect just do it this way!

Comment: @Mat I actually tested what CygnusX1 is suggesting and it works correctly in VC2008. The virtual function table get's replaced and everything works as it should afterwards.

Comment: Apart from fact, if it works or not, using constructors and destructors this way is *generally* wrong. I have an irresistible impression, that if this piece of code is used, it will surely someday land on thedailywtf.com...

Comment: First, it is a bad idea to call destructor explicitly. Second, it is generally a bad idea in languages without duck typing. With colleagues we even considered just to advise you call the method you need in a correct way: `this->bite_balls(this);` first. But it is not a good thing to do.

Comment: "it is a bad idea to call destructor explicitly" -- it cannot be bad *per se*, since there is a language construct to do exactly that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You got some nasty comments to your question. Now I don't think they are deserved although there may be better ways to do what you want. I understand where you are coming from but actually you are using the destructor the same way you would use the reset function you refuse to write. Actually you gain nothing from calling a destructor  since calling a distructor has nothing to do with actually deleting or resetting anything unless you actually write the code to do it within the destructor.

As to your question about the placement new:

As you may know already the placement new doesn't allocate any memory so calling it will just create the object in the same place. I understand that is exactly what you want but it's just not ncessary. Since you don't call delete on your object just destroy, you can set destroyed to true without initializing the class.

To sum it up:

1. If you use the destructor as a regular virtual function you gain nothing. Don't do it since you can get into trouble if a destructor is called twice
2. A call to a placement new will not allocate memory and just perform needless initialization. You can just set destroyed to true.

To do what you want to do correctly and gain the benefits of destructors, you should overload the new and delete operators of your classes and use the normal  destruction mechanism. You can then opt not to release the memory but mark it as invalid or maybe release most of the memory but leave the pointer pointing to some flags.

**EDIT**

Following the comments I decided to sum up all the risks I see and the risks that others have pointed out:

1. Accessing invalid pointer in a multi-threaded environment: Using your method a class may be accessed after the destructor has run but before the destroyed flag is set (As to your question in one of the comments - shared_ptr is for most purposes thread safe)
2. Relaying on a behavior you don't totally control: Your method relies on the way destructors auto call the destructors of other members which are not dynamically allocated: This means that you still have to release dynamically allocates memory specifically, You have no control on how exactly this is implemented, You have no control on the order in which other destructors are called.
3. Relaying on a behavior you don't totally control (Point 2): You are relaying on the way a compiler implements the part of the destructor which calls other destructors you have no way in telling whether your code will be portable or even how will it handle calling it twice.
4. Destructors may be called twice: Depending on your implementation this may cause memory leaks or heap corruption unless you guard against releasing the same memory twice. You claim you guard against that case by calling the placement new - However in a multi-threading environment this is not guaranteed further more you assume that all memory allocations are done by the default constructor - depending on your specific implementation this may or may not be true.
5. You are going against the better judgment of everyone that answered your question or commented on it - You may be onto something genius but most probably you are just shooting yourself in the leg by limiting your implementation to a small subset of situations where it will work correctly. It is like when you use the wrong screwdriver you will eventually end up damaging the screw. In the same way using a language construct in a way it was not intended to be used may end up with a buggy program - Destructors are intended to be called from delete and from the code generated by the compiler to clear the stack. Using it directly is not wise.

And I repeat my suggestion - overload delete and new for what you want

Comment: "Actually you gain nothing from calling a destructor since calling a distructor has nothing to do with actually deleting or reseting anything unless you actually write the code to do it within the destructor." -- Note that a destructor automatically calls the destructors of all the class members. Using the destructor over implementing `reset()` myself saves me the trouble of iterating over all the members and calling `reset()` myself (provided the members have such function).

Comment: @CygnusX1 You are right but automatic destruction is only for class variables that are not allocated dynamically. Your approach is very risky in my opinion - You rely on automatic behavior that is correct only for part of your class data. Also since for those variables nothing is released there is little gain. However I see how this maight help you - Just remember to guard against double calls to destructors or trying to release already released memory.

Comment: Good points. However, I don't see (yet) any additional risk of double-destructing or double-releasing when using the above construct (except for multi-threading hazards). Even if `destroy()` is called twice, it should still work fine, I think? This is because when I destroy an object manually I immediately create a new one in its place. Only calling `delete` twice at the same pointer could lead to an error, but that would be wrong even without the above construct.

Comment: @CygnusX1 - I tried to sum up all the risks I and others see. Edited the answer

Comment: Thank you for your time summing it all up, although I don't see the some of the problems as real problems.

Comment: @CygnusX1 Now you are starting to get it. The constructor you are calling will only construct the base class. What will happen when the destructor of the derived class is called on members that are already destructed? What will happen to all the dynamic memory that will not be allocated in the derived class but will be deleted twice? Your code can only work under very limited circumstances.

Comment: Since the destructor is virtual, the second call to the destructor will destroy *only* the base class. Everything will be fine (at least with that respect)

Comment: @CygnusX1 That is where you are wrong. If you have class B derived from A with a virtual destructor. destroy is defined in A and it calls this virtual destructor then you agree that the destructor of B is called as well. When you call the placement new on A only the constructor of A is called. Now when you delete the instance of class B the destructor of B will be called again but all the specific members of B will remain uninitialized. Come on you must see it by now...

Comment: I don't think so. You have a pointer to some memory location where you invoke the `delete` operation, which in turn calls *some* destructor. Which destructor (of A or of B or something else) is resolved at run time through virtuality, and since I created an A-object there, the destructor of A will be called there, not B. Most compilers resolve virtuality through virtual-table pointer which is stored at that location where I placement-new the A object.

Comment: @CygnusX1 very good point. I'm always glad to learn something new. I actually implemented your scheme and it appears to work correctly. However my tests show that at least on VC2008 there is no need for the placement new. The virtual function table gets fixed after the call to the destructor. I would still be very careful in using what you suggested but for the simple test case I made it certainly works correctly. If you like we can delete all the comments above where we just fail to understand each other. All in all your implementation is very cool although I wouldn't use it in production.

Comment: Glad to hear we understand each other now, and I agree that some (but not all) comments can be removed. Now, knowing how the code can work, what may happen that it will fail? :)

Comment: @CygnusX1 Well the way virtual functions table is implemented is compiler specific. The whole concept my fail. Also there is the mutli-threading issue. You still can't know for sure what the destructor does so calling it twice may be dangerous. If delete is called before calling destroy you are in the same spot you were to begin with. If the base class contains dynamic memory you have to make sure all of it is allocated in the default constructor or that you check you don't free already freed memory

Answer (score 5):

> There is a suggestion of using smart pointers. In fact - I am doing that, but my references are circular. I could use some fully-fledged garbage collectors, but since I know myself where (and when!) circle chains can be broken, I want to take advantage of that myself.

Then you can explicitly null-ify ([reset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982757.aspx) if you are using `shared_ptr`) one of the circular smart pointers and break the cycle.

Alternatively, if you know where the cycles will be in advance, you should also be able to *avoid* them in advance using `weak_ptr` in place of some of the `shared_ptr`s.

**--- EDIT ---**

> If an object referenced by weak pointers only would merely get flagged as "invalid" and release control over all its contained pointers (is this sentence clear?), I would be happy.

Then `weak_ptr::expired` should make you happy :)

Comment: Explicitly nullify smart pointers - In my case, it means going through all my classes, implementing `reset` method for each, which will nullify all smart pointers of each class. Together with marking that the object is no longer usable. Yes, I can do this, but that's the job that destructors were invented for in the first place.

Comment: @CygnusX1 So you are using your own smart pointer? No you don't need to _"nullify all smart pointers of each class"_. You just need to null-ify the one that keeps the cycle alive. And no, that's not _"the job that destructors were invented for in the first place"_ - you are not destroying the smart pointer, you are just changing its state.

Comment: I think I worded it incorrectly. What I meant is - I would have to implement `reset()` member function which would reset all member pointers of that object (and not all pointers everywhere). I want to break cycles by making the nodes "weak" and not by making edges "weak".

Comment: @CygnusX1 So, what's the problem? You'll need to invalidate one of the in-cycle pointers _somehow_. Whether you invalidate it in a member function or somewhere else, you'll have to do it. Whether you do it by null-ifying the pointer or by zombifying the object it points to is logically the same. I think you are approaching this whole thing from the wrong angle - if you know where the cycle is, then you know which pointer to null-ify to break it, so why can't you just do it?

Comment: I don't know which pointer (edge in a cycle) to break. I know which object (node in a cycle) to break.

Comment: @CygnusX1 Well, you said _"I know myself where (and when!) circle chains can be broken"_, which kind of implied the opposite. OK, since you don't actually know that, hold a **single** "well-known" `shared_ptr` to the object and all the other pointers will be `weak_ptr`. When the time comes to free the object, just reset this one `shared_ptr` and all of the `weak_ptr`s will automatically expire (i.e. their `weak_ptr::expired` will return true).

Comment: "since you don't actually know that" - know what? Where to break the cycle? I know by a node (it's also a valid knowledge and way of thinking about breaking cycles). What you are suggesting is a one global array of shared_ptr-s to all objects that I create. Once I know the node is not needed, I release it. Is that right? OK. It's a way to go. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As with everyone else, I recommend you should just use `weak_ptr`. But you asked why your approach doesn't work as well. There are some issue of elegant implementation and separation of concerns that your code walks all over, but I won't argue those. Instead, I'll just point out that your code is horribly not thread-safe.

Consider the following execution sequence of two threads of control:

```
// Thread One
if ( ! ptr -> isDestroyed() ) {     // Step One
    // ... interruption ...
    ptr -> something();             // Step Three
```

And the other:

```
// Thread Two
ptr -> destroy();                   // Step Two
```

By the time step 3 comes around, the pointer is no longer valid. Now it's possible to fix this by implementing `lock()` or similar, but now you've incurred the possibility of defects about not releasing locks. The reason that everyone is recommending `weak_ptr` is that this whole class of problems has been worked out both in the interface of the class and its implementations.

One issue remains. You seem to want a facility where you can kill an object at will. This is the tantamount to requiring that the only pointers to an object are weak ones, that no strong ones are present that would break when the object was manually deleted. (I'll stipulate that this isn't a bad idea, though I must say I don't know why it's not in your case.) You can get this by building on top of `weak_ptr` and `shared_ptr`. These classes are generic, so if you want to disallow `shared_ptr` access to `BaseClass`, then you can write a specialization for `shared_ptr<BaseClass>` that behaves differently. Hide one instance of `shared_ptr<BaseClass>` to prevent deletion and provide such pointers through a factory method under your control.

In this model the semantics of `destroy()` need attention. The first choice is whether you want synchronous or asynchronous operation. A synchronous `destroy()` would block until all external pointers are released and not allow the issuing of new ones. (I'll assume that copy constructors are already disabled on the pointer.) There are two kinds of asynchronous `destroy()`. The simpler of the two fails if there still exist external references. Calling `unique()` on the hidden `shared_ptr()` makes this an easy implementation. The more complicated one acts like an asynchronous I/O call, scheduling the destruction to happen at some point in the future, presumably as soon as all external references are gone. This function might be called `mark_for_death()` to reflect the semantics, since the object might or might not be destroyed at return time.

Comment: Good point! I haven't thought about thread safety. However, by using smart pointers I don't gain thread-safety either, do I? Any member function (be it `destroy` as above or `reset` as suggested) would have to be guarded in some way. If I change the behavior of `shared_ptr` this part of code would have to be guarded as well.

Comment: Putting a single guard system on a smart pointer rather than guards on each member function is indeed one of the reasons to use smart pointers. It's the strongest reason from the perspective of design patterns, since it separates concerns well.

The thread safety of `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr` has already been fully worked out. The only other concern on top of that is the semantics of `destroy()`; I've added a paragraph on that topic to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using one appropriate of the smart pointer patterns instead. Behavior of accessing a deleted object is still undefined and a 'zombie' flag won't really help. The memory that was associated with the object instance that was deleted could be immediately occupied by any other object created, thus accessing the zombie flag isn't an information you can trust.

IMHO the placement new operator

```
new(this) BaseClass();
```

used in your `destroy()` method won't really help. Depends a bit how this method is intended to be used. Instead of deleting derived objects or inside destructors of deleted objects. In the latter case the memory will be freed anyway.

**UPDATE:**

According to your edit, wouldn't it be better to use the shared pointer/weak pointer idiom to solve the occurrence of circular references. I would consider these as a design flaw otherwise.

Comment: I am destroying the object, I am not deleting the underlying memory. Instead, I am reusing the memory myself to create a new object there.

Comment: Yes, I've seen that after writing the answer, it's suspect anyway.

Comment: It's suspect - I agree. That's why I want to know all the risks I am taking before committing myself to it.

Comment: I don't really understand your response from the "IMHO" part. I am never deleting any memory in the "destroy()" method, so no memory will be freed. weak_ptr is... weak... if I access an object through it, the object may not exist anymore.

Comment: In case you really have circular shared pointer references this means some object which destruction depends on destruction of the object pointed to still holds a reference to it, right? In this case the weak_ptr is OK, the pointee shouldn't be used after destruction.

Comment: I want all pointers to be valid, except for those belonging to objects that are getting zombified. Think of it as adding a flag "weak" on an object, and not on a pointer. If an object is "weak" then all its member pointers should not be used. Otherwise, all pointers should remain "strong".

Comment: @CygnusX1 have you considered... *adding a flag*? You can `reset()` whatever pointers it holds when that flag gets set.

Comment: @CygnusX1, that makes almost no sense. You are writing what you want, but not why the other, already present solution does not work for you. I smell XY problem.

Comment: "You can reset() whatever pointers it holds when that flag gets set" -- yes, and I have suggested that myself as well. But this requires writing a `reset()` function for every class, which will iterate over all its members and then calling `reset` on ever member pointer (which in most cases means all members). But this is sort of soft-destructor.